# unfound package after python package installation on OSX

Tags: python, macos, opencv, numpy

I am a newbie to `python`. I a trying to install `OpenCV 3.0` in `OSX` (el capitan). The python version is `2.7.10`

I downloaded the source. When I try to build, I get get this message

```
ImportError: No module named numpy.distutils
-- Could NOT find PythonInterp: Found unsuitable version "1.4", but required is at least "3.4" (found /home/myusername/.pyenv/shims/python3)
-- Could NOT find PythonInterp: Found unsuitable version "1.4", but required is at least "3.2" (found /home/myusername/.pyenv/shims/python3)
```

Could someone help ?

EDIT : the output of the `cmake`

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
> -D PYTHON2_PACKAGES_PATH=/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages \
> -D PYTHON2_LIBRARY=/home/username/.pyenv/shims/python \
> -D PYTHON2_INCLUDE_DIR=/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 \
> -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
> -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON \
> -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/home/username/Desktop/Sites/echopen/py_opencv/opencv_contrib ..
-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 7.3.0.7030031
-- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 7.3.0.7030031
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FSIGNED_CHAR
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FSIGNED_CHAR - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FSIGNED_CHAR
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FSIGNED_CHAR - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_W
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_W - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_W
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_W - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WALL
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WALL - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WALL
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WALL - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_RETURN_TYPE
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_RETURN_TYPE - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_RETURN_TYPE
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_RETURN_TYPE - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_ADDRESS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_ADDRESS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_ADDRESS
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_ADDRESS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_SEQUENCE_POINT
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_SEQUENCE_POINT - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_SEQUENCE_POINT
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_SEQUENCE_POINT - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WFORMAT
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WFORMAT - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WFORMAT
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WFORMAT - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_FORMAT_SECURITY
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_FORMAT_SECURITY - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_FORMAT_SECURITY
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_FORMAT_SECURITY - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WMISSING_DECLARATIONS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WMISSING_DECLARATIONS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WMISSING_DECLARATIONS
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WMISSING_DECLARATIONS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WMISSING_PROTOTYPES
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WMISSING_PROTOTYPES - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WMISSING_PROTOTYPES
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WMISSING_PROTOTYPES - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSTRICT_PROTOTYPES
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSTRICT_PROTOTYPES - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSTRICT_PROTOTYPES
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSTRICT_PROTOTYPES - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WUNDEF
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WUNDEF - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WUNDEF
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WUNDEF - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WINIT_SELF
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WINIT_SELF - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WINIT_SELF
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WINIT_SELF - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WPOINTER_ARITH
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WPOINTER_ARITH - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WPOINTER_ARITH
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WPOINTER_ARITH - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSHADOW
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSHADOW - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSHADOW
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSHADOW - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSIGN_PROMO
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSIGN_PROMO - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSIGN_PROMO
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSIGN_PROMO - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_NARROWING
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_NARROWING - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_NARROWING
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_NARROWING - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_DELETE_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_DELETE_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_DELETE_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_DELETE_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNNAMED_TYPE_TEMPLATE_ARGS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNNAMED_TYPE_TEMPLATE_ARGS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNNAMED_TYPE_TEMPLATE_ARGS
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNNAMED_TYPE_TEMPLATE_ARGS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FDIAGNOSTICS_SHOW_OPTION
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FDIAGNOSTICS_SHOW_OPTION - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FDIAGNOSTICS_SHOW_OPTION
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FDIAGNOSTICS_SHOW_OPTION - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_LONG_LONG
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_LONG_LONG - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_LONG_LONG
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_LONG_LONG - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_QUNUSED_ARGUMENTS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_QUNUSED_ARGUMENTS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_QUNUSED_ARGUMENTS
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_QUNUSED_ARGUMENTS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SEMICOLON_BEFORE_METHOD_BODY
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SEMICOLON_BEFORE_METHOD_BODY - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_SEMICOLON_BEFORE_METHOD_BODY
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_SEMICOLON_BEFORE_METHOD_BODY - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FNO_OMIT_FRAME_POINTER
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FNO_OMIT_FRAME_POINTER - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FNO_OMIT_FRAME_POINTER
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FNO_OMIT_FRAME_POINTER - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MSSE
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MSSE - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_MSSE
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_MSSE - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MSSE2
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MSSE2 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_MSSE2
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_MSSE2 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MNO_AVX
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MNO_AVX - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_MNO_AVX
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_MNO_AVX - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MSSE3
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MSSE3 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_MSSE3
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_MSSE3 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MNO_SSSE3
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MNO_SSSE3 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_MNO_SSSE3
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_MNO_SSSE3 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MNO_SSE4_1
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MNO_SSE4_1 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_MNO_SSE4_1
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_MNO_SSE4_1 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MNO_SSE4_2
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MNO_SSE4_2 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_MNO_SSE4_2
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_MNO_SSE4_2 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FVISIBILITY_HIDDEN
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FVISIBILITY_HIDDEN - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FVISIBILITY_HIDDEN
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FVISIBILITY_HIDDEN - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FVISIBILITY_INLINES_HIDDEN
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FVISIBILITY_INLINES_HIDDEN - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FVISIBILITY_INLINES_HIDDEN
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FVISIBILITY_INLINES_HIDDEN - Success
-- Check if the system is big endian
-- Searching 16 bit integer
-- Looking for sys/types.h
-- Looking for sys/types.h - found
-- Looking for stdint.h
-- Looking for stdint.h - found
-- Looking for stddef.h
-- Looking for stddef.h - found
-- Check size of unsigned short
-- Check size of unsigned short - done
-- Using unsigned short
-- Check if the system is big endian - little endian
-- Looking for fseeko
-- Looking for fseeko - found
-- Looking for unistd.h
-- Looking for unistd.h - found
-- Check size of off64_t
-- Check size of off64_t - failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_SHORTEN_64_TO_32
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_SHORTEN_64_TO_32 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_ATTRIBUTES
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_ATTRIBUTES - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_STRICT_PROTOTYPES
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_STRICT_PROTOTYPES - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_MISSING_PROTOTYPES
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_MISSING_PROTOTYPES - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_MISSING_DECLARATIONS
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_MISSING_DECLARATIONS - Success
-- Looking for assert.h
-- Looking for assert.h - found
-- Looking for fcntl.h
-- Looking for fcntl.h - found
-- Looking for io.h
-- Looking for io.h - not found
-- Looking for jbg_newlen
-- Looking for jbg_newlen - not found
-- Looking for mmap
-- Looking for mmap - found
-- Looking for search.h
-- Looking for search.h - found
-- Looking for string.h
-- Looking for string.h - found
-- Looking for unistd.h
-- Looking for unistd.h - found
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED_BUT_SET_VARIABLE
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED_BUT_SET_VARIABLE - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNDEF
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNDEF - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_SIGN_COMPARE
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_SIGN_COMPARE - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_CAST_ALIGN
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_CAST_ALIGN - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_SHADOW
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_SHADOW - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_MAYBE_UNINITIALIZED
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_MAYBE_UNINITIALIZED - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_POINTER_TO_INT_CAST
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_POINTER_TO_INT_CAST - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_INT_TO_POINTER_CAST
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_INT_TO_POINTER_CAST - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED_PARAMETER
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED_PARAMETER - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_MISSING_DECLARATIONS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_MISSING_DECLARATIONS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED_PARAMETER
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED_PARAMETER - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED_VARIABLE
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED_VARIABLE - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_IMPLICIT_FUNCTION_DECLARATION
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_IMPLICIT_FUNCTION_DECLARATION - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNINITIALIZED
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNINITIALIZED - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED_BUT_SET_PARAMETER
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED_BUT_SET_PARAMETER - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_STRICT_OVERFLOW
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_STRICT_OVERFLOW - Success
-- Looking for semaphore.h
-- Looking for semaphore.h - found
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SHADOW
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SHADOW - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SIGN_COMPARE
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SIGN_COMPARE - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNDEF
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNDEF - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNINITIALIZED
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNINITIALIZED - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SWITCH
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SWITCH - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_PARENTHESES
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_PARENTHESES - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_ARRAY_BOUNDS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_ARRAY_BOUNDS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_EXTRA
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_EXTRA - Success
-- checking for module 'gstreamer-base-1.0'
--   package 'gstreamer-base-1.0' not found
-- checking for module 'gstreamer-video-1.0'
--   package 'gstreamer-video-1.0' not found
-- checking for module 'gstreamer-app-1.0'
--   package 'gstreamer-app-1.0' not found
-- checking for module 'gstreamer-riff-1.0'
--   package 'gstreamer-riff-1.0' not found
-- checking for module 'gstreamer-pbutils-1.0'
--   package 'gstreamer-pbutils-1.0' not found
-- checking for module 'gstreamer-base-0.10'
--   package 'gstreamer-base-0.10' not found
-- checking for module 'gstreamer-video-0.10'
--   package 'gstreamer-video-0.10' not found
-- checking for module 'gstreamer-app-0.10'
--   package 'gstreamer-app-0.10' not found
-- checking for module 'gstreamer-riff-0.10'
--   package 'gstreamer-riff-0.10' not found
-- checking for module 'gstreamer-pbutils-0.10'
--   package 'gstreamer-pbutils-0.10' not found
-- checking for module 'libdc1394-2'
--   package 'libdc1394-2' not found
-- checking for module 'libdc1394'
--   package 'libdc1394' not found
-- checking for module 'libv4l1'
--   package 'libv4l1' not found
-- checking for module 'libv4l2'
--   package 'libv4l2' not found
-- Looking for linux/videodev.h
-- Looking for linux/videodev.h - not found
-- Looking for linux/videodev2.h
-- Looking for linux/videodev2.h - not found
-- Looking for sys/videoio.h
-- Looking for sys/videoio.h - not found
-- checking for module 'libavcodec'
--   package 'libavcodec' not found
-- checking for module 'libavformat'
--   package 'libavformat' not found
-- checking for module 'libavutil'
--   package 'libavutil' not found
-- checking for module 'libswscale'
--   package 'libswscale' not found
-- checking for module 'libavresample'
--   package 'libavresample' not found
-- Looking for libavformat/avformat.h
-- Looking for libavformat/avformat.h - not found
-- Looking for ffmpeg/avformat.h
-- Looking for ffmpeg/avformat.h - not found
-- checking for module 'libgphoto2'
--   package 'libgphoto2' not found
-- ICV: Removing previous unpacked package: /home/username/Desktop/Sites/echopen/py_opencv/opencv/3rdparty/ippicv/unpack
-- ICV: Unpacking ippicv_macosx_20141027.tgz to /home/username/Desktop/Sites/echopen/py_opencv/opencv/3rdparty/ippicv/unpack...
-- ICV: Package successfully downloaded
-- found IPP (ICV version): 8.2.1 [8.2.1]
-- at: /home/username/Desktop/Sites/echopen/py_opencv/opencv/3rdparty/ippicv/unpack/ippicv_osx
-- Could NOT find Doxygen (missing:  DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE) 
-- To enable PlantUML support, set PLANTUML_JAR environment variable or pass -DPLANTUML_JAR=<filepath> option to cmake
-- Found PythonInterp: /home/username/.pyenv/shims/python2.7 (found suitable version "2.7.10", minimum required is "2.7") 
-- Found PythonLibs: /home/username/.pyenv/shims/python (found suitable exact version "2.7.10") 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named numpy.distutils
-- Could NOT find PythonInterp: Found unsuitable version "1.4", but required is at least "3.4" (found /home/username/.pyenv/shims/python3)
-- Could NOT find PythonInterp: Found unsuitable version "1.4", but required is at least "3.2" (found /home/username/.pyenv/shims/python3)
-- Found JNI: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libjawt.dylib  
-- Could NOT find Matlab (missing:  MATLAB_MEX_SCRIPT MATLAB_INCLUDE_DIRS MATLAB_ROOT_DIR MATLAB_LIBRARIES MATLAB_LIBRARY_DIRS MATLAB_MEXEXT MATLAB_ARCH MATLAB_BIN) 
-- VTK is not found. Please set -DVTK_DIR in CMake to VTK build directory, or to VTK install subdirectory with VTKConfig.cmake file
-- Assume that non-module dependency is available: -framework OpenCL (for module opencv_core)
-- Performing Test HAVE_OBJCXX_FOBJC_EXCEPTIONS
-- Performing Test HAVE_OBJCXX_FOBJC_EXCEPTIONS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_DEPRECATED_DECLARATIONS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_DEPRECATED_DECLARATIONS - Success
--   videoio: Removing WinRT API headers by default
-- 
-- General configuration for OpenCV 3.0.0 =====================================
--   Version control:               3.0.0
-- 
--   Platform:
--     Host:                        Darwin 15.3.0 x86_64
--     CMake:                       3.2.3
--     CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
--     CMake build tool:            /opt/local/bin/gmake
--     Configuration:               RELEASE
-- 
--   C/C++:
--     Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
--     C++ Compiler:                /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++  (ver 7.3.0.7030031)
--     C++ flags (Release):         -fsigned-char -W -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-unnamed-type-template-args -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -Qunused-arguments -Wno-semicolon-before-method-body -fno-omit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -mno-avx -msse3 -mno-ssse3 -mno-sse4.1 -mno-sse4.2 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C++ flags (Debug):           -fsigned-char -W -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-unnamed-type-template-args -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -Qunused-arguments -Wno-semicolon-before-method-body -fno-omit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -mno-avx -msse3 -mno-ssse3 -mno-sse4.1 -mno-sse4.2 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
--     C Compiler:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc
--     C flags (Release):           -fsigned-char -W -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-unnamed-type-template-args -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -Qunused-arguments -Wno-semicolon-before-method-body -fno-omit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -mno-avx -msse3 -mno-ssse3 -mno-sse4.1 -mno-sse4.2 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C flags (Debug):             -fsigned-char -W -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-unnamed-type-template-args -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -Qunused-arguments -Wno-semicolon-before-method-body -fno-omit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -mno-avx -msse3 -mno-ssse3 -mno-sse4.1 -mno-sse4.2 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
--     Linker flags (Release):
--     Linker flags (Debug):
--     Precompiled headers:         NO
--     Extra dependencies:          -framework OpenCL -framework Cocoa -framework QTKit -framework QuartzCore -framework AppKit
--     3rdparty dependencies:       libjpeg libwebp libpng libtiff libjasper IlmImf zlib ippicv
-- 
--   OpenCV modules:
--     To be built:                 hal core flann imgproc ml photo video imgcodecs shape videoio highgui objdetect superres ts features2d calib3d stitching videostab
--     Disabled:                    world
--     Disabled by dependency:      -
--     Unavailable:                 cudaarithm cudabgsegm cudacodec cudafeatures2d cudafilters cudaimgproc cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo cudawarping cudev java python2 python3 viz
-- 
--   GUI: 
--     QT:                          NO
--     Cocoa:                       YES
--     OpenGL support:              NO
--     VTK support:                 NO
-- 
--   Media I/O: 
--     ZLib:                        build (ver 1.2.8)
--     JPEG:                        build (ver 90)
--     WEBP:                        build (ver 0.3.1)
--     PNG:                         build (ver 1.5.12)
--     TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.0.2)
--     JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 1.900.1)
--     OpenEXR:                     build (ver 1.7.1)
--     GDAL:                        NO
-- 
--   Video I/O:
--     DC1394 1.x:                  NO
--     DC1394 2.x:                  NO
--     FFMPEG:                      NO
--       codec:                     NO
--       format:                    NO
--       util:                      NO
--       swscale:                   NO
--       resample:                  NO
--       gentoo-style:              NO
--     GStreamer:                   NO
--     OpenNI:                      NO
--     OpenNI PrimeSensor Modules:  NO
--     OpenNI2:                     NO
--     PvAPI:                       NO
--     GigEVisionSDK:               NO
--     QuickTime:                   NO
--     QTKit:                       YES
--     V4L/V4L2:                    NO/NO
--     XIMEA:                       NO
--     gPhoto2:                     NO
-- 
--   Other third-party libraries:
--     Use IPP:                     8.2.1 [8.2.1]
--          at:                     /home/username/Desktop/Sites/echopen/py_opencv/opencv/3rdparty/ippicv/unpack/ippicv_osx
--     Use IPP Async:               NO
--     Use Eigen:                   YES (ver 3.2.7)
--     Use TBB:                     NO
--     Use OpenMP:                  NO
--     Use GCD                      YES
--     Use Concurrency              NO
--     Use C=:                      NO
--     Use pthreads for parallel for:
--                                  NO
--     Use Cuda:                    NO
--     Use OpenCL:                  YES
-- 
--   OpenCL:
--     Version:                     static
--     libraries:                   -framework OpenCL
--     Use AMDFFT:                  NO
--     Use AMDBLAS:                 NO
-- 
--   Python 2:
--     Interpreter:                 /home/username/.pyenv/shims/python2.7 (ver 2.7.10)
-- 
--   Python 3:
--     Interpreter:                 NO
-- 
--   Python (for build):            /home/username/.pyenv/shims/python2.7
-- 
--   Java:
--     ant:                         NO
--     JNI:                         /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/include /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/include/darwin /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/include
--     Java wrappers:               NO
--     Java tests:                  NO
-- 
--   Matlab:
--     mex:                         NO
-- 
--   Documentation:
--     Doxygen:                     NO
--     PlantUML:                    NO
-- 
--   Tests and samples:
--     Tests:                       YES
--     Performance tests:           YES
--     C/C++ Examples:              YES
-- 
--   Install path:                  /usr/local
-- 
--   cvconfig.h is in:              /home/username/Desktop/Sites/echopen/py_opencv/opencv/build
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------
-- 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/username/Desktop/Sites/echopen/py_opencv/opencv/build
```

Comment: Did you install numpy already. Test it with `python -c "import numpy"`.

Comment: @gdlmx I have no output when running your command

Comment: That means your numpy is installed correctly. It seems that you have some version conficts. Maybe posting your entire cmake outputs will be helpful

Comment: @gdlmx thanks, I updated my post !

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this env variable `-D PYTHON2_PACKAGES_PATH=/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages` causes the problem, because your python is installed in `/home/username/.pyenv/shims/`. Your system used the `pyenv` package to isolate different python versions which confuses the `cmake` script for opencv.

Try the following steps:

1. Find out the path of your numpy installation by running `python -c 'import sys, numpy.distutils;print sys.modules["numpy.distutils"]'` in command line.
2. Set the cmake variable `PYTHON2_PACKAGES_PATH` to the `site-packages` folder that contains numpy. `cmake -D PYTHON2_PACKAGES_PATH=/xxx/xxx/site-packages/`

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv#locating-the-python-installation) of `pyenv`, your python installation should be found under `~/.pyenv/versions/2.7.10`

> Each Python version is installed into its own directory under ~/.pyenv/versions.

You should be able to find the site-packages folder in this location.

Comment: thank you, in fact I already found `numpy.distutils` in `System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/` but the problem is that there is no `site-packages` dir in the whole `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7` folder. Do you have an idea ?

Comment: however I printed ` print site.getsitepackages()` and I found ` /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages` and `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python`perhaps I should use the latter ?

Comment: You may also refer to this link : http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/15/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-osx/ to get a step by step tutorial.

Comment: @ZdaR that's what I exactly did ;) but I have a problem with some paths

Comment: when I use `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python`as `PYTHON2_PACKAGES_PATH`, I stil get `ImportError: No module named numpy.distutils` ...

Comment: @ZdaR : thanks. That tutorial uses `virtualenv` but the error message in this post suggests that [pyenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv#understanding-shims) is used here. These two packages are quite different.

Comment: You may skip those steps and get started with the step for building opnecv with cmake.

Comment: @ZdaR that's precisely what I did ;)

Comment: @gdlmx is there a way not to use `/home/username/.pyenv/shims/python` as `PYTHON2_LIBRARY` so that to use the system `python` ? if this is the case how can I find this path

Comment: Yes. Remove the `/home/username/.pyenv/shims/` from your `$PATH`. And prepend the folder of your system python to it. The cmake should be clever enough to find it.